# change the image is not transparent to be transparent with php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to ask, how do I get the first image to be the second picture?
in the sense that the first image of the backgroud is not transparent and will I change to transparant on the image become like the second picture?
how do you do it with php?
I really do not know

Image 1-
[image]
Image 2-
[image]

Please help!

Comment: Image manipulation you are asking about it sounds like? Take a look at http://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html a good php image manpi library. Codeigniter has a built in one but it might not do what you are looking for. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved

Answer (score 0):

if you have only images B&W, it's possible in break the white in all pixel.

```
<?php
  $url = "IUWBw.jpg";
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);//get your image
  //get size
  $width = imagesx($image);
  $height = imagesy($image);
  //create new image
  $out = ImageCreateTrueColor($width,$height);

  //configuration for make alpha color
  imagealphablending($out,false);
  imagesavealpha($out, true);

  for($x = $width-1;$x>=0;$x--){
    for($y = $height-1;$y>=0;$y--){
        $rgb = imagecolorat($image,$x,$y);//get pixel color of original image
        $r =   $rgb >> 16;
        $g =   ord(chr($rgb >> 8)); 
        $b =   ord(chr($rgb));
        if( $rgb != 0 ){ //if pixel is not black
            //if red is the low color
            if($r<$g && $r < $b){
                $alpha =  ($r / 2);
                $g-=$r;$b-=$r; $r=0;
            }
            //if green is the low color
            if($g<$r && $g < $b){
                $alpha =  ($g / 2);
                 $r-=$g;$b-=$g;$g=0;
            }
            //if blue is the low color
            if($b<$r && $b < $g){
                 $alpha =($b / 2);
                $r-=$b; $g-=$b;$b=0;  
            }
            //if we all have equal value
            if($b == $r && $b == $g){
                 $alpha = ($b / 2);
                $r-=$b; $g-=$b;$b=0;  
            }

            $color = $alpha << 24 | $r << 16 | $g << 8 | $b;

            imagesetpixel($out,$x,$y,$color);

        }else{//else is black just write 
                imagesetpixel($out,$x,$y,$rgb);
        }
    }
  }


    $urlout = preg_replace("#(.+).jpe?g#i","$1.png",$url);

    imagepng($out,$urlout);
    echo "image writeted: ".$urlout;
    imagedestroy($out);
    imagedestroy($image);

?>
```

this code looks for the low value of one pixel and subtracts it from the other value. 
 
example: a pixel so the values are, r: 255 g: 226 b: 255. 
he transforms it into r: 29 g: 0 b: 29;

 
now that the pixel has no value in white, it remains to put the appropriate alpha. the value of 'g' divides by 2 before its transformation. divide by 2 because the alpha supports a value of 127 instead of 255.
a = g / 2 = 226/2 = 113.

 
this code also works on color images, but the whole image will be translucent. Except the black.